# How can I convert this winforms application into console application?

Tags: c#

The below code is working fine in Windows Form application, but I need to run it in console.

```
namespace TelnetApp
{
    public partial class TelnetForm : Form
    {
        public TelnetForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Socket clientSocket;

        IPAddress hostAddress;
        public void telnetSocketAsyncEventArgs_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {    
            try
            {    
                if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                {

                    if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Connect)
                    {    
                        MessageBox.Show("Service Is Running", hostAddress.ToString(),
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);    
                    }    
                }    
                else
                {    
                    MessageBox.Show("Service Is not Running", e.SocketError.ToString(),
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                }    
            }

            catch (SocketException ex)
            {    
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Service Is not Running",    
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);    
            }
        }

        private void TelnetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(IPTextBox.Text))
                    return;   
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PortTextBox.Text))    
                    return;
                int port;    
                hostAddress = IPAddress.Parse(IPTextBox.Text);
                int.TryParse(PortTextBox.Text, out port);
                clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                SocketAsyncEventArgs telnetSocketAsyncEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                telnetSocketAsyncEventArgs.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(hostAddress,port);
                telnetSocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed += new
                EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(telnetSocketAsyncEventArgs_Completed);
                clientSocket.ConnectAsync(telnetSocketAsyncEventArgs);

            }    
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {    
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Service Is not Running",    
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }    
            finally
            {

            }                   
          }    
       } 
    }
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read the [guide to asking a good question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and show [what you have tried](http://whatyouhavetried.com).

Comment: `Project/Properties/Application/Output Type <-- Console Application`

Answer (score 2):

Create a new Console application project, copy the code into it and put the code from the button click event into the main method. You may need to change the other method signatures to include `static`.

Remove calls to `MessageBox` and replace them with calls to `Console.WriteLine`. Also, as you don't have text boxes for the user to enter data, you'll need to parse command line arguments, which is easy as they come in as an array in `static void Main(string[] args)`.

Then, start the debugger and check whether you have problems.

Comment: You're trying for this http://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal aren't you ;)

Comment: :-D Didn't know that this existed - anyway, you could help ;-)

Comment: Damn - didn't get it. Question is at -7... :-/ Thanks anyway :-D

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the code into a console app and add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and add `using System.Windows.Forms;` to your using directives to preserve the message boxes.

If you don't want the message boxes then use `Console.WriteLine` instead.